# Where to add authorship/copyright information about my code in Node and React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have worked on a product for the past year and I am soon going to release it (not free), my question is, how do I handle the authorship/copyright of the code?

What are the "available places" for adding such information? The only thing I know of that might come close to that is the information that I write for the `package.json` with `npm init`. But where else can I add the information so that its there in the production build of both the node and the react?

As far as React goes, I have no clue where to add that kind of information.

What are the best/correct practices?

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is most likely to add the license you are publishing your code under at the top of each script. There is no central place to add authorship. So `package.json` is not an option here.
Since this can be a pretty repetitive process, you may want to use an npm script like `add-license` ([Click here for more details](https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-license))

Answer (score 0):

Add license files to the source and to head of each source file if they are useful individually. Indicate in your README what the license is and what files the license doesn't apply to (e.g. artwork). [Here's an example](https://code.habd.as/comfusion/after-dark) using an AGPL license. Avoid creating crayon licenses as tempting as it may seem. And [choose your license(s)](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://choosealicense.com/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjKvuaYg7fuAhXBbCsKHV0BByEQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3kZXNUtVc10cMf13bQmUC4) wisely. Send more detailed licensing questions to https://opensource.stackexchange.com/.